# Eslint error : Do not nest ternary expressions

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a project using React.js and I have this error using the eslint:

> Do not nest ternary expressions

Here is my code:

```
const MyApp = () => {

return (
<>
{(var1 && var2) ? (
          <Tag1 />
        ) : error ? (
          <Tag2 />
        ) : null}
</>); 
}
```

Do you know how can I do to solve that? I thought to use if, but I think I cannot in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by the [no-nested-ternaries](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-nested-ternary) eslint rule.

Linter rules are suggestions on how you should write your code, they point out best practices but not necessarily real "errors".

If it shows an "error" here, that is because someone (or a preconfigured ruleset) decided to enable this rule as "error level" for your project.
Generally, there is no need to change your code unless you (or someone on your team) wants to forbid this style of coding. Technically, it is perfectly valid code and will work.

If you are on a team, talk with your team about the sense of that rule. If you are alone on your project, think if you want this rule or not and disable it in your `.eslintrc` file.

Personally I think that most suggestions on how to write this code instead given in other answers make it a lot less readable, so I'd keep it as this and disable the rule if I were you.

Answer (score 8):

I'd use an IIFE instead, so you can `if`/`else`.

```
{
  (() => {
    if (var1 && var2) return <Tag1 />;
    if (error) return <Tag2 />;
    return null;
  })()
}
```

For the `MyApp` component, this simplifies to:

```
const MyApp = () => {
    if (var1 && var2) return <Tag1 />;
    if (error) return <Tag2 />;
    return null;
};
```

Comment: I updated my code because I cannot do that in my code :/

Comment: Why can't you do that? Your new code actually makes this easier, without the need for the outer brackets

Answer (score 2):

Well you can move that logic outside JSX, e.g.

```
function Component(){

..........
let content = null;
if (var1 && var2) content = < Tag1 / > ;
else if (error) content = < Tag2 / > ;

return <>{content}</>


}
```

Comment: I updated my code because I cannot do that in my code :/

Comment: @Tom why can't you do that in your code? check updated answer

Answer (score -1):

Deal with it before reaching your return statement:

```js
const MyApp = () => {

let outTag = null;
if (var1 && var2) {
    outTag = <tag1 />;
}
else if (error) {
    outTag = <Tag2 />;
}

return (
<>
    {outTag}
</>); 
}
```