# How should you fix "Do not nest ternary expressions" for rendering components conditionaly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code below, eslint raises some error

```
{authModal.mode === 'login' ? <Login /> : authModal.mode === 'register' ? <SignUp /> : <ForgotPassword />}
```

Error: Do not nest ternary expressions. eslint(no-nested-ternary)

I have come up with 3 ways not to get the error:

1. check for each case

   ```
   {authModal.mode === 'login' && <Login />}
   {authModal.mode === 'register' && <SignUp />}
   {authModal.mode === 'forgotPassword' && <ForgotPassword />}
   ```
2. if/else inside function

   ```
   {(() => {
     if (authModal.mode === 'login') {
       return <Login />;
     }
     if (authModal.mode === 'register') {
       return <SignUp />;
     }
     return <ForgotPassword />;
   })()}
   ```
3. switch case inside function

   ```
   {(() => {
     switch (authModal.mode) {
       case 'login':
         return <Login />;
       case 'register':
         return <SignUp />;
       case 'forgotPassword':
         return <ForgotPassword />;
       default:
         throw new Error('Invalid auth mode');
     }
   })()}
   ```

In addition to avoiding an error, I want to solve the following.
Assuming that the 3 components are heavy components (performance wise),
I would like to know the best solution that is best for performance. Please let me know if there's alternative solution to mine.

Comment: This is opinion-based, but it's also a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67028246/eslint-error-do-not-nest-ternary-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [`useMemo`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) with an object lookup:

Compare to [José's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77133249/10289265), using `useMemo` makes sure it refreshes only when `authModal.mode` changes, which provides  better performance.

```js
const authComponent = useMemo(() => ({
  'login': <Login />,
  'register': <SignUp />,
  'forgotPassword': <ForgotPassword />
})[authModal.mode], [authModal.mode]);

return (
  <>
    {authComponent}
  </>
)
```

But if you're looking for even better performance, combining `useMemo` with your `switch` solution might be a better choice since it doesn't creates all three elements in memory at once when there's essentially only one element will be rendered. The optimization might be minor but it will be more significant if you have lots of elements or those elements are heavy to initialize:

```js
const authComponent = useMemo(() => {
  switch (authModal.mode) {
    case 'login':
      return <Login />;
    case 'register':
      return <SignUp />;
    case 'forgotPassword':
      return <ForgotPassword />;
    default:
      throw new Error('Invalid auth mode');
  }
}, [authModal.mode]);

return (
  <>
    {authComponent}
  </>
)
```

Comment: Appreciate your solution! Quick question: Compared to José's answer, do you get any benefits from using useMemo? Mainly I want to know if you see differences in performance. (Say that the 3 components are heavy components.)

Comment: I've added some explaination to this solution, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use objects for this spot.

```
const autModal = {
  mode: 'login'
}

const modes = {
  login: <Login />,
  register: <Singup />
  forgotPassword: <ForgotPassword />
}

() => modes[autModal.mode]
```